# required plugin Kotlin is disabled error in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

My app is not even using kotlin then how it is asking me for kotlin plugin? it shows this error below,

```
12:16 AM    Plugin Error
                    Problems found loading plugins:
                    Plugin "Android Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "WIFI ADB ULTIMATE" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Android APK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Firebase Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Firebase Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.
                    Plugin "App Links Assi... (show balloon)
```

How to resolve this, Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: File - > Settings -> Plugins

And turn them on

Answer (score 0):

Go to your plugins in your ide then uninstall kotlin and reinstall it if you'd like.